# Legality of reading unpaid e-book/research paper (ex. from genlib/sci-hub)

Tags: copyright, internet, licensing

What is the legality of reading unpaid e-book/research paper (ex. from site like genlib/sci-hub) (In my case, in Indonesia). is someone eligible to be charged because they downloaded the e-book/research paper from that site? or is it just permissible as long as they keep it themself (They dont sell it & They dont share it to many people)?

Edit:

1. Add "research paper from sci-hub"
2. Add country of origin: Indonesia

Comment: Are you asking if it is legal to get ebooks from a library?

Comment: Not library in general, but site like genlib/sci-hub

Comment: This site? http://gen.lib.rus.ec/

Comment: yes youre right

Comment: Do you know who runs that site?

Comment: I dont know, I just exploring some site to get ebooks and I get genlib & sci-hub

Comment: Where are you from? What country?

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: [Cross-site duplicate on Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/112509/), specifically mentioning Library Genesis.

Comment: @Molot hey, Indonesia

Answer (score 12):

Most of the works available on Libgen are illegal: they have infringed copyright by putting copies there. Any copying of a protected work, done without permission of the copyright owner, is copyright infringement. That includes downloading from libgen.

Comment: Libgen is committing copyright violation. Users are not. There is no case of somebody being sued and lost *just* for downloading content for personal use.

Comment: Not in my country, for example. In Poland downloading and reading something that's freely available, while morally dubious, is perfectly legal.

Comment: Not being sued does not mean not being illegal. Downloading copyrighted material is not legal, because you are making an unauthorized copy of copyrighted material. The damage caused is so low that nobody will probably bother suing you, but if someone did you probably would lose the case and had to pay the damage produced (which I guess it couldn't be more than the cost of the book plus some administration costs)

Comment: @julodnik and lawyer costs, which would easily dwarf the previous two :D

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta Oh, the Netherlands would disagree with you there.

Comment: @julodnik your statement is true in some jurisdictions and under some copyright law systems, but totally false in others.

Comment: @Mast: Point of distinction: _"However, the European Court of Justice found that system to be illegal and the government quickly moved to ban downloading from unauthorized sources."_ ([link](https://torrentfreak.com/dutch-continue-to-curb-illegal-downloading-but-what-about-streaming-180222/)) It's not illegal to download content where the copyright was violated. The Netherlands have simply resorted to "download licensing" which is technically (and pedantically) irrespective of the copyright status of the downloaded works. Though of course that is the underlying intention, just not explicitly.

Comment: This really differs for different countries. In mamy places it reall is *not illegal*. Not just tolerated, not illegal.

Comment: @Flater The system called illegal is the system that previously allowed obtaining content due to a levy on blank media. Better explained [here](https://mashable.com/2014/04/10/downloading-pirated-content-is-now-illegal-in-the-netherlands/). That doesn't appear to hold bearing on my comment. Giacomo claimed there is no case of somebody being sued, while in the Netherlands (and other countries) I vaguely recall this has happened (although it's a bit muddy due to most of those users also sharing, not just downloading).

Comment: _"I guess it couldn't be more than the cost of the book plus some administration costs"_  Dangerous assumption.  In the US, for example, there are large (some would say ridiculous) minimum penalties for copyright infringement, and a judge can apply additional punitive damages if the infringement was "willful."

Comment: Hey thanks for the answers, please check the question again, I added "research paper from sci-hub"

Comment: The part that is not personally clear to me about sci-hub is the proportion of illegal papers there, given the disproportionately high number of open access science journals plus the higher probability of author submission.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've specified Indonesia, I'll take this opportunity to highlight something fairly unique. [According to the World Intellectual Property Organization](https://wipolex.wipo.int/en/legislation/details/15600), Indonesia "exempts the non-commercial reproduction and distribution of copyrighted materials through information and technology media from the scope of the authors’ exclusive rights." This is the first jurisdiction I've heard of where not only is the consumer in the clear, but the **distributor** may also not be violating Indonesian copyright law. Do note the non-commercial clause there though, I'm not familiar with whether genlib/sci-hub are commerical.

I'm relying on Google Translate here, and am in general not familiar with Indonesian law, but the legal basis for this is Article 43(d) of their copyright act (available via WIPO link above). Additionally, Indonesia is a jurisdiction that ordinarily allows private use copying via Article 46, though note copying of an entire book is excluded from this in section 2(b). Also note most jurisdictions which allow private use copying further specify that the source must be a legal one, Google Translate isn't quite good enough here for me to confirm whether Indonesia is one.

Again, take this answer with a grain of salt as I am not familiar with Indonesian law or language.

Comment: "though note copying of an entire book is excluded from this in section 2(b)." -- In this case then things like Library Genesis are not considered. They are excluded since they generally distribute the whole book.